# Plot bin sizes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, binning

I've cut my data into several bins and would like to plot the size/frequency of each bin in a histogram. With the y-axis being the bin frequency and the x labels being the bin ranges.

Currently I have:

```
out = pd.cut(data.hour, bins = filter_values, include_lowest = True)
counts = pd.value_counts(out)
print(counts)`
```

Which outputs:

```
[0, 5]      1000
(19, 23]       0
(15, 19]       0
(11, 15]       0
(8, 11]        0
(5, 8]         0
Name: hour, dtype: int64
```

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo (step by step):

```
In [51]: filter_values = [0, 5, 11, 15, 19, 23]
```

generating sample DF:

```
In [52]: df = pd.DataFrame({'hour':np.random.randint(0, 23, 20)})

In [53]: df
Out[53]:
    hour
0      5
1     18
2     19
3      5
4     16
5     18
6     18
7     19
8      0
9      8
10    14
11    20
12     9
13    22
14     8
15     0
16     0
17     4
18    13
19    18
```

building bins

```
In [54]: out = pd.cut(data.hour, bins = filter_values, include_lowest = True)

In [55]: out
Out[55]:
0       [0, 5]
1     (11, 15]
2     (15, 19]
3     (11, 15]
4      (5, 11]
5       [0, 5]
6       [0, 5]
7       [0, 5]
8       [0, 5]
9      (5, 11]
10      [0, 5]
11      [0, 5]
12    (11, 15]
13    (15, 19]
14     (5, 11]
15    (15, 19]
16     (5, 11]
17    (19, 23]
18     (5, 11]
19      [0, 5]
Name: hour, dtype: category
Categories (5, object): [[0, 5] < (5, 11] < (11, 15] < (15, 19] < (19, 23]]
```

counts:

```
In [56]: counts = out.value_counts(sort=False)

In [57]: counts
Out[57]:
[0, 5]      8
(5, 11]     5
(11, 15]    3
(15, 19]    3
(19, 23]    1
Name: hour, dtype: int64
```

plot

```
In [58]: counts.plot.bar(rot=False)
Out[58]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xa427b00>
```

[image]

Comment: Your efforts shall not go unsung!

Comment: can I get you to weigh in on my answer [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43020297/2336654) I answered late. I'm also on the road without my laptop and can't run any code 

Comment: @piRSquared, sure!